# How to convert time and date to Unix timestamp on Apache PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a tuple containing (date, time, ip, id)

```
(23/04/2014, 19:14:30,192.168.5.28, al00000)
```

and I need to convert date and time to Unix timestamp

```
(1398280470, 192.168.5.28, al00000)
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try googling `unixtimestamp apache pig` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ref :** http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions

**Input :**

```
23/04/2014,19:14:30,192.168.5.28,al00000
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',')  AS (date:chararray,time:chararray,ip:chararray,id:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToUnixTime(ToDate(CONCAT(date, time),'dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss', 'GMT')) AS unix_time, ip, id;
```

**Output :**

```
(1398280470,192.168.5.28,al00000)
```